# How to retrieve only the file name in a link to a pdf using sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the following links for pdf files in a SQL table column and I want to get the names of the file alone.

```
href="http://www2.xxxxxxx.com/Images/Content/misc/PDF/xx-xxxx-Warranty-Dealer.pdf
href="http://www2.xxxxxxx.com/Images/Content/misc/PDF/Tobaccocertificationform2008.pdf
```

In this case, I want the result to be

```
xx-xxxx-Warranty-Dealer.pdf
Tobaccocertificationform2008.pdf
```

How can I read the name alone from the link

Comment: What have you tried? There are about a million ways to do this. Most of them will involve REVERSE, CHARINDEX, SUBSTRING.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders I tried REVERSE as suggested by another developer and I could reach the solution

Comment: Show what you tried, don't just _talk_ about it.

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

```
REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(STRING_FIELD),CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(STRING_FIELD))-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this. I tried to use a few string functions as possible. These functions (especially REVERSE) can have pretty big negative impacts on performance.

```
select right(Href, charindex('/', REVERSE(Href), 0) - 1)
```

Comment: I tried REVERSE as suggested by you and I could reach the solution